# Laravel 5 - Custom helper class with global access

Tags: php, laravel-5, acl, ioc-container, rbac

My custom helper class is this:

Located in app/bootstrap/ACL.php

```
class ACL {

    public function __construct(){
       //Get user from session
       //Get user permission array
    }

    public function isAllowed($key){
        return 'calling from ACL class';
    }

}
```

Now, I need to access this ACL class inside all of the project controllers. So
I `require_once 'ACL.php';` in my app.php file.

Then inside my controller I can do the following:

```
class UserController extends Controller {

    public function editDetails() {

        $acl = new \ACL();
        echo $acl->isAllowed('edit-details');

        //below is the code to edit details

    }
}
```

This code works, but I feel there should be a Laravel 5 proper way to do this.
I want to know:

1) Is this approach OK or is there a better way to achieve this?

2) Without doing `$acl = new \ACL();` in every controller, can I use a global variable?
Or something like this `ACL::isAllowed('edit-details');`

3) How can I run `$acl->isAllowed('edit-details')` condition in Blade templates properly?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply add it to the classmaps?

```
"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
      "app/Classes"
  ]
}
```

You can then put your class into the "/classes" folder under app and just use it.
Just run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and then you can use it like other classes in laravel.